# Unity using Animation and Ragdoll

Tags: unity, physics, software-engineering

The question is simple, but I can't resolve it for a couple of days. I have an enemy model with ragdoll attached and also a couple of animations(e.g. idle, walk, run). It seems that ragdoll work only when animator is stopped and vice versa. What I want is when the animation is playing all the forces are applied too, e.g. when I shoot enemy he still walking by animation and and ragdoll corresponds with AddForce(). I tried to find appropriate tutorial for that, watched ton of youtube videos and read a lot of unity forums, but no success. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link looks interesting and provides almost that what I need, maybe it can help somebody too
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/animfollow-active-ragdoll-is-now-free-to-download.220812/